# VS-Code Remote-Container Clone Command does nothing/is not working

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to follow along in this blog: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/07/27/containers-edu

Currently my platform is Windows 10 Pro Build 19041 and VSCode 1.49.2

I have installed Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 (WSL2) and Docker Desktop 2.3.0.46911 using WSL2 for the backend. All services needed seem to be started and running.

The extensions I have installed for VSCode are Remote-Containers and Remote-WSL.

When following along in the above blog post, I get to the point of trying to clone the sample repository using the Remote-Containers: Clone command. But whenever I try to execute the command, nothing happens. There is no way to pull up the command to enter the repository I need to clone. I click on the command in the command palate and it just disappears and does nothing.

Does anyone know a workaround or fix?

Answer (score 0):

I figured the problem out on my system. Remote-Containers: Clone didn't do anything when I executed the command because git was not installed on my windows machine. After installing git, executing Remote-Containers: Clone worked and prompted for the repository location.

There was no error message to indicate git was not installed when running the Remote-Containers: Clone command, like there is if docker is not running.